# Rails: `ipads_path' error message with iPad.rb model and ipads_session controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm making a website with a page where users can sign up to win an iPad. I created a model `ipad.rb` and an `ipads_controller.rb` and there were three columns in the migration for name, email and twitter handle. I was surprised when Rails didn't create routes automatically (I thought it was supposed to do that always).

I added this in the routes file

```
resource :ipad
  match '/signup',  :to => 'ipads#new'
```

When I tried to create the sign up form, I got this error message before fully completing it

```
undefined method `ipads_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000103a64ec0>:0x00000103a49aa8>
```

This surprised me because why was it plural?

So far I've only created a form in `new.html.erb` and the model `ipad.rb` and two actions in the `ipads_controller.rb` `new` and `create`.

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?  i.e. why does Rails think I need a method `ipads_path`. Also note that I had created a model IPad.rb but deleted it and the migrations.

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Win an iPad</h1>

<h1>Sign up for iPad</h1>

<%= form_for(@ipad) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**ipad.rb**

```
class Ipad < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :name, :email, :twitter

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :name, :presence => true,
                 :length   => { :maximum => 50 }
validates :email, :presence => true,
                  :format   => { :with => email_regex }, 
                  :uniqueness => true

end
```

**ipads_controller.rb**

```
class IpadsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @ipad = Ipad.new
    @title = "iPad Contest"
  end

  def create
    @ipad = Ipad.new(params[:ipad])
    if @ipad.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      @title = "iPad Contest"
      render 'new'
    end
  end


end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Enki::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace 'admin' do
    resource :session

    resources :posts, :pages do
      post 'preview', :on => :collection
    end
    resources :comments
    resources :undo_items do
      post 'undo', :on => :member
    end

    match 'health(/:action)' => 'health', :action => 'index', :as => :health



    root :to => 'dashboard#show'
  end

  resources :archives, :only => [:index]
  resources :pages, :only => [:show]

  resource :ipad
  match '/signup',  :to => 'ipads#new'

  constraints :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :day => /\d{2}/ do
    get ':year/:month/:day/:slug/comments'  => 'comments#index'
    post ':year/:month/:day/:slug/comments' => 'comments#create'
    get ':year/:month/:day/:slug/comments/new' => 'comments#new'
    get ':year/:month/:day/:slug' => 'posts#show'
  end

  scope :to => 'posts#index' do
    get 'posts.:format', :as => :formatted_posts
    get '(:tag)', :as => :posts
  end

  root :to => 'posts#index'
end
```

Comment: I think your choice of models could probably be improved.  While what you are doing isn't "wrong", exactly, it's not particularly clear code, nor is it likely to be very reusable.  I'd consider refactoring it so that you have a Contest model which has Entry models associated with it.  It seems weird to have a model named IPad that maps to a table of user information.

Comment: I agree. I'm a noob.  This might be the second time i've created a model (outside of following along in a book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resource 'ipad' should be plural in the routes, i.e.

> resources :ipads

Comment: Thanks, if you have time can you explain why? for example, there's a resource for 'session' but it's singular....

Comment: If your controller was `iPadController` (`ipad_controller.rb`) then you'd use a singular resource name.  Instead, you have `iPadsController` so it's looking for a plural declaration.